# how to get the output path with Robot Framework API?

Tags: robotframework

I want to create a listener for the Robot Framework, I want to the use the current output path in the listener, how to get the output path via Robot Framework API?

Comment: What do you mean by "current output path"?

Comment: @JanKovařík Yes, I want to get the current output path

Comment: The current path to output.xml, and the html logs?

Comment: @AlexBruce have you checked listener methods documentation? (http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#listener-interface-methods) Is the `path` argument of either `output_file` or `log_file` or `report_file` what you need?

Comment: @JanKovařík yes, the path is  argument of either output_file or log_file or report_file, but I want to get it in start_suit, do you have any solution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Robot Framework provides several [automatic variables](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#automatic-variables) that can be used on your Robot-Tests.

To get the `${OUTPUT DIR}` from your Python code, you can call the [`Get Variable Value`](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/libraries/BuiltIn.html#Get%20Variable%20Value) keyword directly by doing:

```
from robot.libraries.BuiltIn import BuiltIn
built_in = BuiltIn()
output_dir = built_in.get_variable_value('${OUTPUT DIR}')
```

Comment: @AlexBruce you can even consider to upvote the answer :)